# Mobile firefox and mp3 support

Tags: php, firefox, mobile, mp3, ogg

I'm trying to build a website where user uploads mp3 files. When testing, the mobile firefox player disappears when the play button in clicked. I understand that firefox can only play ogg files. What can i use to convert uploaded mp3 files to ogg format in order to have full support of mp3 playing throughout all the web and mobile browsers.

any explanation how soundcloud manages to have full support of all files even of mp3 in firefox mobile.

thanx

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert these files. Trust me. Firefox can play mp3 files yet it is a very tricky hack. This hack is done by soundmanager2. Go check it out. It offers the best compatabilty with all browsers. You will definately want it for your website!

I am assuming soundcloud is similar to soundmanager2. I have no idea how it works, audio is definately tricky to go about in web dev.

If anything, my best guess would be a flash fallback...

Also converting the audio files msy be taxing your bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla reached out to us to work together getting [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) working on firefox os, and Mozilla is now a CreateJS sponsor.  Our examples like [SoundGrid](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS/demos/soundGrid) should work everywhere.  You might also find the [Mobile Safe Tutorial](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mobile%20Safe%20Approach/) useful.

Hope that helps.